# What are providers about?

Tags: neovim

When I run `:CheckHealth` in neovim, I obtain:

```
Python 3 provider (optional) ~
- pyenv: Path: /usr/share/pyenv/libexec/pyenv
- pyenv: Root: /home/USERNAME/.pyenv
- Using: g:python3_host_prog = "/home/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/neovim/bin/python"
- Executable: /home/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/neovim/bin/python
- Python version: 3.12.1
- pynvim version: 0.5.0
- OK Latest pynvim is installed.

Python virtualenv ~
- OK no $VIRTUAL_ENV

Ruby provider (optional) ~
- Disabled (g:loaded_ruby_provider=0).

Node.js provider (optional) ~
- Disabled (g:loaded_node_provider=0).

Perl provider (optional) ~
- Disabled (g:loaded_perl_provider=0).
```

I have disabled Ruby, Node.js  and Perl providers with:

```
vim.g.loaded_ruby_provider = 0
vim.g.loaded_node_provider = 0
vim.g.loaded_perl_provider = 0
```

in my `init.lua`, because they slowed down significantly nvim startup time.

I frequently code in Python, so I don't know whether I can disable that provider too.

- What are providers?
- What do they do?
- Can I disable the Python provider as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim can embed other languages. It allows plugin author to write code in another language than VimScript.

If you don't plan to use plugins that are written in these languages you don't need these providers.

I'm aware of a small number of plugins that requires the Python provider.

- [ultisnip](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)
- [vim-isort](https://github.com/fisadev/vim-isort)
- [vimspector](https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector)

I suspect that a number of Neovim plugins will rely on the `Node.js` provider (but this need to be confirmed).

I believe the ruby and perl provider are rarely used or only for ruby and perl specific plugins (but this need to be confirmed).